# AJAX и NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ajax

Есть одна страница, на ней много различных AJAX запросов.
Как лучше отправлять запросы? На отдельные файлы? или на один, но при этом в зависимости от 
переданных данных на сервер подключать определенную функцию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разные файлы, это я так понимаю разные сервера (в случае с nodeJS).

Я считаю, это зависит от связи функционала, например корзину и чат на одном сайте лучше сделать разными серверами, а вот добавление и удаление товара, например в одном

Что касается ресурсов, то конечно два разных сервера использующие одни и те же данные, это не желательно.